# Who are the characters that Mr. Sinister is planning to enlist in X-Men '97 #1 (comic book)?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, x-men-97

Just finished reading [*X-Men '97* #1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/110354/x-men_97_2024_1), the comic book tie-in and prelude to the *X-Men '97* animated TV series. In the comic book, Mr. Sinister is looking at computer screens showing various characters (presumably mutants who appeared in the *X-Men '97* predecessor, *X-Men: The Animated Series*), and it seems he's planning to enlist these characters as "new help."

[image]

Sabretooth is definitely one of them, but I don't recognize the others. Can anyone identify the rest of the characters on those screens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pictured centre are;

**[Sabretooth](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Victor_Creed_(Earth-616))**
[image]

**[Arclight](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/arclight/4005-13369/)**
[image]

**[Prism](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Prism_(Robbie)_(Earth-616))**
[image]

**[Harpoon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kodiak_Noatak_(Earth-616))**
[image]

**[Riptide](https://x-men.fandom.com/wiki/Riptide)**
[image]

**[Siena Blaze](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix9/blazesienaxm.htm)** (bottom left)
[image]

**[Hazard](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Carter_Ryking_(Earth-616)) (AKA Carter Ryking)** (bottom right)
[image]

In canon Sabretooth, Arclight, Harpoon and Riptide were formerly members of a mutant supervillain gang called [The Marauders](https://x-men.fandom.com/wiki/Marauders).